# Form input values not remain after flash error message

Tags: laravel-5

How to solve above issue? I want to keep test even after a validation failure in the submission. But after session error message is passed all the entered data will be gone.

Comment: Did you try `return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();`?

Comment: Glad it worked, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To re-fill the form with the input data again, check the input validation then if validation fails, redirect the user back along with his input data and validation errors.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        // your validation rules.
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
// Continue your app logic.
```

You'll find more information in [Laravel validation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

Answer (score 0):

You should send back the input also to the view.

Like Sameh Salama already mentioned, use the following code:

```
function () {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Notice the withInput() function, it returns the old input.

Use it in the View as

```
<input type="something" value="{{$input->first_something}}" />
```